# Regular expression tools or methods that identifies the alternate that matched some target text?

Tags: regex, capturing-group

In my debugging of regular expression, I need to find out which alternate among the alternatives actually resulted the match. For example, for the target string:

```
"foo"
```

with the regular expression:

```
"f.*|other"
```

I need a way to know that in the above regular expression, the alternate `"f.*"` actually resulted the match.

In some complex regular expression with many alternates, this is very challenging for debug.

Comment: Have you tried using something like http://regexpal.com/ ?

Answer (score 1):

If each alternative is enclosed in its own capturing group, you know only one of those groups can participate in the match.  The others will return a null or undefined value when you query them.  So you just iterate through the capture groups until you find one that's not null.  The detailed process will depend on which regex flavor and/or programming language you're using; there's a great deal of variation.

So, if your regex is `(f.*)|(other)` and it matches `foo`, group #1 will contain `foo` and group #2 will be null (or `nil`, or `undef`, depending on the language you're using; but be aware that an empty string usually indicates a successful match that didn't consume any characters).

Answer (score 0):

```
(?<MYRESULT>(?<RESULT1>f.*)|(?<RESULT2>other))
```

Now both MYRESULT and RESULT1 or RESULT2 will contain your match.